# how to make a discord bot mention someone in a specific channel (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

im making a "mini game chat bot" and i want the bot to have different endings.
when someone unlocks an ending i would like to be notified so i can keep track of how many endings that person has unlocked (no i wont add roles to keep track because if my calculations are correct the bot will have like 200 different endings).
i want to make it so that,
for example, someone says B3 in #general and the bot answers in #endings

> @(person who used the command) unlocked the ending "I probably
>   shouldn't have said that..."

```
    case 'B3':
            message.channel.send('Umm.. What?'); 
            const B3ending = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
            .setTitle('Congratulations!) 
            .setColor(0x8CF1EC)
            .setDescription('You unlocked the ending "I probably shouldn't have said that..."');
            message.channel.send(B3ending);
        break;
```

Comment: Do you want the embed aswell?

Comment: yes, everything in that code is intentional, there just needs to be a message added that is sent to a specific channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first you would need to get the channel somehow, maybe by id:

```js
const endChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(id);
```

After that you can just use the send method alongside `msg.author`

```js
endChannel.send(`${message.author} here's the ending`, { embed: B3ending });
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply!
you really saved me here